# Implementing TDMA in UnetStack

Tags: communication, unetstack

I want to simulate a simple TDMA protocol for underwater communication networks, where each node transmits at a regular intervals. How do I implement this in [UnetStack](http://www.unetstack.net/)?

The UnetStack [document on MAC](http://www.unetstack.net/doc/html/mac.html) gives examples of Simple and Throttled MAC protocols, but how can I get the nodes to transmit at a regular interval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical agent written using UnetStack can add [new behaviors to itself](http://org-arl.github.io/fjage/doc/html/behaviors.html).

In order to transmit at regular intervals as required by a node in TDMA like protocol, your agent can instruct the [PHY agent](http://www.unetstack.net/doc/html/svc-10-phy.html) to transmit regularly. This can be implemented using ticker behaviour.

A [TickerBehavior](https://org-arl.github.io/fjage/doc/html/behaviors.html#ticker-behavior) runs repeatedly with a specified delay between invocations. A TickerBehavior can be added to your agent with this code:

```
add new TickerBehavior(1000*slotlength, {
   phy << new TxFrameReq(to: nodeAddress, type: Physical.DATA)
})
```

where `slotlength` is in seconds and `nodeAddress` is the address of the node you are trying to transmit the information to. For more information on [TxFrameReq you can check out the documentation](http://www.unetstack.net/javadoc/org/arl/unet/phy/TxFrameReq.html).